# Анимация через toggleClass

Tags: javascript, css

Есть код раскрывающегося меню:

```
e.mobileOpen.on("click",function(){
n(this).toggleClass("_show", 500),e.mobileContainer.toggleClass("_show", 500)})}
```

Нужно сделать так что бы меню расскрывалось плавно, знаю как это сделать на jquery но незнаю как на чистом js, заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `toggleClass` — `el.classList.toggle('CLASS')`, а также не забыть добавить `transition` для элемента, который собираемся анимировать с помощью добавления класса.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('div[role="button"]'),
      menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

btn.onclick = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('_opened');
}
```

```css
div[role="button"] {
  width: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.menu._opened {
  height: 100px;
}

.menu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div role="button">Toggle</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>lorem</li>
      <li>dolor</li>
      <li>sit</li>
      <li>amet</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо